# Sangean MMR-88 DAB radio stuck at "PC wizard.."

Tags: radios

I've rendered my [Sangean MMR-88 DAB radio](http://www.sangean.eu/products/product.asp?l=2&cid=5&mid=225) (alias Sangean Survivor DAB+) unusable by selecting *System* → *Software Upgrade*.

The display says "PC wizard.." and the radio is unresponsive. I've tried pressing and holding the power button for a couple of seconds, hoping that this would cause a hard reset, but that's not what happened.

How do I make my radio work again?

Comment: Although there is a slight relevance because this question is about outdoor equipment such as DAB Radio, sadly it is likely to get any useful answer other than suggestions to take it to the OEM/service center. I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't fit into the scope defined for The Great Outdoors.

Comment: Bringing the device to a service center was not at all what the accepted answer suggested. Judging by the upvotes, other people, too, ran into the device's bad UX when trying to cancel a software upgrade.
Also, [questions about](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8948/what-would-happen-if-i-use-a-usa-gmrs-frs-two-way-radio-in-europe) and [recommendations for radios](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3304/recommendations-for-two-way-radios-to-use-while-skiing) seem to be on-topic on this site.

Comment: I agree to the fact that this has received upvotes and you indeed have received an answer other than taking to service center, which is good! However, I'd hate to see people citing this question as an example of what's acceptable and come up with questions to fix electronic equipment that are used for some or the other outdoor activity. For instance, you referred to recommendations for radios as a well-received question, agreed, but at the same time the same post can be flagged as a question looking for preshopping advice, and that won't be wrong either!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to remove the battery from the battery compartment at the bottom of the radio. This turned off the radio. After turning the radio on, it's responsive again.

Mind that for this to work, the radio mustn't be connected to another power source with a USB cable. Meaning you should unplug the radio before removing the battery so it actually turns off.

This trick is not described in the part of the [manual](http://www.sangean.eu/support/download/Manual/V1/20170307_3A81aQ1000040_MMR-88DAB_GB_V1.pdf) that talks about software upgrades.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh: Yeah I know :-D But I was assuming that removing the battery would **not** turn that thing off due to its solar panel. Also, when the radio is charging using a USB cable, removing the battery doesn't in fact turn the radio off, so *how* to turn the device off is actually the core of my answer^^.